# Detect column resize event in angular ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I need to do some operation after re-sizing the column in ui-grid. I didn't find any column re-size event in ui-grid. Please provide a way to detect column re-size event in ui-grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check your `enableColumnResizing` to be enabled.

```
enableColumnResizing: true
```

Then you might want to use a watcher like this:

```
$scope.$watch('gridOptions.$gridScope.isColumnResizing', 
    function (newValue, oldValue) {        
        // do something here        
    });
```

Would be a good way to create a dedicated plugin for that purpose and plug it as a custom plugin then to your grid.

**UPDATE:**
If above snippet isn't working:

I just found in their source code following part:

```
var publicApi = {
  events: {
    /**
     * @ngdoc event
     * @name columnSizeChanged
     * @eventOf  ui.grid.resizeColumns.api:PublicApi
     * @description raised when column is resized
     * <pre>
     *      gridApi.colResizable.on.columnSizeChanged(scope,function(colDef, deltaChange){})
     * </pre>
     * @param {object} colDef the column that was resized
     * @param {integer} delta of the column size change
     */
    colResizable: {
      columnSizeChanged: function (colDef, deltaChange) {
      }
    }
  }
};
grid.api.registerEventsFromObject(publicApi.events);
```

So, in your grid options object it'd be:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
   enableColumnResizing: true,
   ...,
   onRegisterApi : function(gridApi) {            
     $scope.gridApi = gridApi; 
     $scope.gridApi.colResizable.on.columnSizeChanged($scope, function(colDef, deltaChange) {
       console.log('resized #############'); 
     });            
   }
};
```

And finally in html:

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ...></div>
```

Comment: Its not working. $watch is not calling when I resizing the columns in the grid.

Comment: @Aravinder did you check you have `gridOptions` field in your $scope with all other options defined for your grid?

Comment: In gridOptions, $gridScope variable is not there. How do I put $gridScope in to gridOptions

Comment: Thank you Meleshko. It worked with minor changes. Please update your answer with below code.$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function( gridApi ) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    $scope.gridApi.colResizable.on.columnSizeChanged( $scope, function(colDef, deltaChange) {
        console.log('resized #############');
    });
};

Comment: I needed to know the new column width. The event doesn't give you that, so to get the new width I did this (in TypeScript): `gridApi.colResizable.on.columnSizeChanged(this.$scope, (colDef, deltaChange) => {
 var column = gridApi.grid.columns.filter(x => x.name == colDef.name)[0];
 if (column) {
  console.log(``${colDef.name} resized by ${deltaChange} to ${column.width}``);
 }
});`